# Instantiate empty type-hinted list

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have the following code:

```py
from typing import List, NewType

MultiList = NewType("MultiList", List[List[int]])

def myfunc():
  multi: MultiList = []
  # More stuff here
```

The code works fine, it's just my IDE (PyCharm) doesn't like the instantiation of `multi` to an empty list, I get this error:

```
"Expected type 'MultiList', got 'list[list[int]]' instead"
```

I mean, a `MultiList` *is* a `list[list[int]]`, so I really don't know why it's complaining. Unless it's because the list is empty, but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me either.

It's not the end of the world, the code works just fine, I'd just like to know why it's marked as wrong.

Comment: That's intentional - the whole point of [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) is to make _distinct_ types, _"a value of type `Original` cannot be used in places where a value of type `Derived` is expected"_, so you don't e.g. confuse heights and weights even though they're both numbers: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=abd3e0c9fa959406e7edee81b59f9d55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire purpose of the [`typing.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) is to distinguish a type from another and treat it as a subtype. You annotate it as `MultiList`, which is treated as a subtype of `list`, so assigning a `list` instance is *wrong*.

You need to instantiate `MultiList` properly. Example:

```py
def myfunc():
    multi: MultiList = MultiList([])
```

If you wanted a type *alias* instead, then you should not use `NewType`, but [`TypeAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) instead:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

MultiList: TypeAlias = list[list[int]]

def myfunc():
    multi: MultiList = []
```

**PS**: Unless you are using an outdated Python version, you should use the standard [generic alias types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type), i.e. `list` instead of `typing.List`.

Comment: Both of these work and I think either matches what I have in my head (thank you), but I'm not quite clear on the difference between a subtype and a type alias?

Comment: @BenTaylor Well, I am not sure what to tell you about _subtype_ other than point you to the fundamentals of type theory... A type alias is (as the name implies) simply an alias for a specific type. Its purpose is basically to allow you to have a shorter notation and/or more expressive name for a type. I suppose `MultiList` may be more expressive to you than `list[list[int]]` and it is shorter. Its _meaning_ is the same. A _subtype_ is **not** the same type, but one derived from it.

Comment: Thanks. Please don't edit my question though unless I've clearly made an error or something is very unclear.

Comment: @BenTaylor I am afraid that is not how this site works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit The important part is to never alter the _intent_ of the original question, which I don't think I've done. All I did was fix a few poorly worded sentences and improve the formatting in a few places to improve the overall readability. Its nothing personal. My apologies, if this offended you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just mean "list of lists of ints", then don't use NewType:

```
MultiList = List[List[int]]
```

NewType is for if you *don't* want arbitrary lists of lists of ints to be treated as a MultiList. With NewType, static type checkers will only treat an object as a MultiList if you explicitly call MultiList:

```
MultiList = NewType("MultiList", List[List[int]])
multi: MultiList = MultiList([])
```